# 301 redirection in .htaccess file not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm attempting to redirect an internal link via .htaccess file and it's not working. Below is my .htaccess file '# Redirects'.

How might I better structure the code to allow working redirection links?

```
# Use PHP 5.3

AddType application/x-httpd-php53 .php 

# Redirect www to non-www

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# Redirects

Redirect 301 /oldpage http://domain/newpage

# Start Hotlink Protection

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]

# EXPIRES CACHING

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/js "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: what exactly is not working, this rule `Redirect 301 /oldpage http://domain/newpage` ?

Comment: Make sure that: (1) mod_alias is enabled. (2) your browser didn't 'remember' a previous redirect (use a temporary redirect when trying to get a redirect to work and only change it to 301 (permanent) when everything is working fine!) (3) Make sure you are using Redirect as specified in [the docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your redirect statement is part of mod_alias, but all the rest of the rewrite rules you have belong to mod_rewrite. Those two modules processes the request at different points of the processing pipeline, so if you use them concurrently, sometimes they'll not play nicely with each other. You should just use mod_rewrite in this case as well as **putting the redirect rule BEFORE your wordpress routing rules**. This is because wordpress will route what you actually want to redirect.

So:

```
# Use PHP 5.3

AddType application/x-httpd-php53 .php 

# Redirect www to non-www

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

#### INSERT THE REDIRECTS HERE
# Redirects

RewriteRule ^oldpage(.*)$ http://domain/newpage$1 [L,R=301]


# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

### Remove the redirect from here

# Start Hotlink Protection

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

And then the rest of your htaccess file